# How to make this site responsive consisting of clockdown counter?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have made this site([http://koulick-project.surge.sh/](http://final_year.surge.sh/))as a project but cannot make it fully responsive. How to make it responsive, so that it looks good on mobile/tablets. So far, I could make the headings and text responsive. But cannot make the circles for the clock responsive.
Here is my Html file-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Pragmatic Mates s.r.o. - http://pragmaticmates.com">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/css/coming_soon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-SfTiTlX6kk+qitfevl/7LibUOeJWlt9rbyDn92a1DqWOw9vWG2MFoays0sgObmWazO5BQPiFucnnEAjpAB+/Sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>JWOC Coming Soon</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div  class="centerdiv">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jwoc2k20" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></i>
    </a>

    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/jwoc/" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-3x"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
        <div class="section">
            <div class="section">
                <div id="particles-js">
                    <break>
                    <h1 style="color:white"><b>JWOC</b></h1>
                    <h1 style="color:white"><b> COMMENCING SOON</b></h1>
                    <hr>
                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="countdown countdown-container container">
    <div class="clock row">
        <div class="clock-item clock-days countdown-time-value col-xs-3 col sm-3">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div id="canvas-days" class="clock-canvas"></div>

                    <div class="text">
                        <p class="val">0</p>
                        <p class="type-days type-time">DAYS</p>
                    </div><!-- /.text -->
                </div><!-- /.inner -->
            </div><!-- /.wrap -->
        </div><!-- /.clock-item -->

        <div class="clock-item clock-hours countdown-time-value col-xs-3 col sm-3 ">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div id="canvas-hours" class="clock-canvas"></div>

                    <div class="text">
                        <p class="val">0</p>
                        <p class="type-hours type-time">HOURS</p>
                    </div><!-- /.text -->
                </div><!-- /.inner -->
            </div><!-- /.wrap -->
        </div><!-- /.clock-item -->
        
        
        <div class="clock-item clock-minutes countdown-time-value col-xs-3 col sm-3 ">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div id="canvas-minutes" class="clock-canvas"></div>

                    <div class="text">
                        <p class="val">0</p>
                        <p class="type-minutes type-time">MINUTES</p>
                    </div><!-- /.text -->
                </div><!-- /.inner -->
            </div><!-- /.wrap -->
        </div><!-- /.clock-item -->

        <div class="clock-item clock-seconds countdown-time-value col-xs-3 col sm-3 ">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div id="canvas-seconds" class="clock-canvas"></div>

                    <div class="text">
                        <p class="val">0</p>
                        <p class="type-seconds type-time">SECONDS</p>
                    </div><!-- /.text -->
                </div><!-- /.inner -->
            </div><!-- /.wrap -->
        </div><!-- /.clock-item -->
        
    </div><!-- /.clock -->
    <hr>
</div><!-- /.countdown-wrapper -->


<!-- footer section -->







<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/kinetic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.final-countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="particles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $('document').ready(function() {
        'use strict';
        
        $('.countdown').final_countdown({
            'start': 2062139200,
            'end': 2088461320,
            'now': 2087461319        
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Css file-

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}

html {
    background-image: url('../img/open.jpeg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}

body {
    background-color: rgba(44,62,80 , 0.6 );
    background-image: url('../img/open1.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    font-family: 'Raleway', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
#particles-js
{
    z-index: 99999;
    height: 500%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: left;
}

.particles-js-canvas-el{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
h1{
    font-size: 70px;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

a{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px; 
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    line-height: 110px;
    
}
a i{
    transition: all 0.3s linear; 
}
a:hover i{
    transform: scale(1.4);
}
.fa-linkedin{
    color: #0097e6;
}
.fa-facebook{
    color: #3b5998;
}

/*
.countdown-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);

}
*/
.clock-item .inner {
    height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%;
}

.clock-canvas {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}



.text {
    color: #fff;    
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;  
    margin-top: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    width: 100%;
}
.text .val {
    font-size: 50px;
}

.text .type-time {
    font-size: 20px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 393px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    h1{
        font-size: 40px;
        letter-spacing: 10px;
    }
    .text {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .text .val {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .text .type-time {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .clock-item .inner {    
        width: 150%;
    }
```

}

Can anyone please help.

Comment: first remove `height: 100vh;overflow:hidden;` from body, then change `col-sm-3` to `col-6 col-sm-3`

Comment: Here is the source code link- https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dHwnz6fIHxm91G0y2B3Clx1s2T827Jf1?usp=sharing

Comment: @LawrenceCherone done

Comment: actually it would be `col-xs-6` not `col-6` as your using v3, then use media query to reduce the size of the heading text when on mobile <=360px size switch out for `6vw` etc vs px then it scales

Answer (score 0):

Try using a column break to split up the timer into multiple rows on smaller screen sizes.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#column-breaks

Tablet+

```
D H M S
```

Phone

```
D H
M S
```

Comment: OP is using v3.3.5

Comment: Same idea - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-example-wrapping